# Yii framework CJUIautocomplete showing error

Tags: php, yii

I am just newbie to the [yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). Currently I have two tables 
one for `sales` and other for `stores`
`Sales table` is looking like this

```
==============
      sales
  ==============
  id
  store_id
```

`store table` is looking like this

```
 ==============
      Stores
  ==============
  id
  store_name
  store_location
```

Now in sales view form(_form.php) I have rendered both sales and stores.
  In sales controller the code for action create is like this

```
  public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Sales;
    $stores = new Stores;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Sales']$_POST['Stores']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Sales'];
      $stores->attributes = $_POST['Stores'];
      $valid = $model->validate();
      $valid = $stores->validate();
      if($valid)
      {
        $stores->save(false);
        $model->store_id = $stores->getPrimaryKey();
        $model->save(false);
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'stores' => $stores,
    ));
  }
```

To get all the stores name in dropdown list I made my code like this

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($stores,'store_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($stores,'store_name', CHtml::listData(Stores::model()->findAll(), 'store_name', 'store_name'), array('empty'=>'--Select--')) ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($stores,'store_name'); ?>
  </div>
```

But here I want the cjuiautocomplete field so that when someone will press any key then it will start to show the suggesions stores name. For that I just came through [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/162/a-simple-action-for-cjuiautocomplete/)

and just like the docs I made the EAutoCompleteAction.php under protected/extension directory
  Then I just made my controller code like this in sales controller

```
 public function actions()
    {
      return array(
        'aclist'=>array(
          'class'=>'application.extensions.EAutoCompleteAction',
          'model'=>'Stores', //My model's class name
          'attribute'=>'store_name', //The attribute of the model i will search
        ),
      );
    }
```

and in view file of sales(_form.php) I made the code like this

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($stores,'store_name'); ?>
    <?php 
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
      'attribute'=>'store_name',
        'model'=>$stores,
        'sourceUrl'=>array('stores/store_name'),
        'name'=>'store_name',
        'options'=>array(
          'minLength'=>'3',
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
          'size'=>45,
          'maxlength'=>45,
        ),
  )); ?>
```

After all when I am doing the search by keywords it is showing 404 error in console panel of firebug.
  The requested search url in firebug was like this (ads was my search query in store name field)

```
http://localhost/WebApp/index.php?r=stores/store_name&term=ads
```

any one here for help?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change action name from sample `aclist` into `store_name`:

```
public function actions()
{
  return array(
    'store_name'=>array( // << Array key is action name
      'class'=>'application.extensions.EAutoCompleteAction',
      'model'=>'Stores', //My model's class name
      'attribute'=>'store_name', //The attribute of the model i will search
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Still its showing 404 not found error in console tab of firefox.

Comment: Have you got any error details when you open url in tab, instead of console?

Comment: yes..for both url and console I am only getting 404 error. By the way I want to get the storesname in the form field.

Comment: When you have 404, it simply means that you are pointing to wrong controller, or action. Do you have `StoresController`, and `actionStore_name`? Note: I'm not quite sure how yii resolves action names with `_`. Your autocomplete name is `store_name`, you should have it in `$_POST`.

Comment: hi @PeterM I got the solution and its working now.. BUt can you help me another query similar to this?

Comment: If you have solution for your problem, please post it as answers so other could benefit. If you have different question, please ask different question.